# the "inspector" screen is not available for this applacation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-devtools

[image]

```
class _BottomNavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const _BottomNavigationBar({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      top: false,
      bottom: true,
      left: true,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          _BottomNavigationBar(),
          _BottomNavigationBar(),
          _BottomNavigationBar(),
          _BottomNavigationBar(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _NavigationBarItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const _NavigationBarItem({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(child: Text('item'));
  }
```

> i am meeting this mistake in this window
> i did a lot ways but they didnot work they didnt work

Comment: how you are building app and what are you as test device

Comment: I am creating chat app and i am using navigation button widget